# Gandhari's curse to Shakuni after his death

Tags: mahabharata, gandhari, shakuni

I read in a recent news article that after the war, Gandhari cursed that Shakuni's kingdom ,i.e., Gandhar, will never have peace. Is this mentioned in the Mahabharat or it's just a folklore? Also this gives rise to another question, can someone be cursed after they have already died?

Comment: I wanted to ask the very same question. Does anyone know? @Rickross

Comment: Just a folklore.

Comment: @Naveen It's not even folklore, it's a popular internet myth, which is not supported at all by Vyāsa's Mahābhārata. Gāndhārī gave no curse to Śakuni, as per Mahābhārata. It's surprising why this question got so many votes.

Answer (score 1):

Her curse was to Krishna, not Shakuni.

First the reference from the [scripture](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m11/m11024.htm):

> "Gandhari said ... Since deliberately, O slayer of Madhu, thou wert
> indifferent to this universal carnage, therefore, O mighty-armed one,
> thou shouldst reap the fruit of this act. By the little merit I have
> acquired through waiting dutifully on my husband, by that merit so
> difficult to attain, I shall **curse thee**, O wielder of the discus and
> the mace! Since thou wert indifferent to the Kurus and the Pandavas
> whilst they slew each other, therefore, O Govinda, thou shalt be the
> slayer of thy own kinsmen! **In the thirty-sixth year from this, O
> slayer of Madhu, thou shalt, after causing the slaughter of thy
> kinsmen and friends and sons, perish by disgusting means in the
> wilderness.** The ladies of thy race, deprived of sons, kinsmen, and
> friends, shall weep and cry even as these ladies of the Bharata
> race!’"